# netbeans cannot find include file on remote tool chain

Tags: c, gcc, netbeans

I am moving from intellij to NetBeans and am hitting an issue with code assist for remote C projects.

I have the set up as below, with the correct directories added under code assist. However NetBeans reports two types of problem with the red underline and light-bulb

1. `cannot find include file #Include <gst/gst.h.>` + many others.
2. `Unable to resolve identifier .....` from include file gst.h.

When running build from NetBeans , it uploads and comiles the code on the remote machine with no errors reported and compile happens as expected.

What am I doing wrong in my set up?

```
Local NetBeans Machine
    Windows 10 
    Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101) 
    Java: 1.8.0_91; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.91-b15 

Remote Build Host 
    SSH with PPK (password protected) 
    centos 7 
    Build Tools: GNU GCC 5.4.0 

Options -> code Assist -> C compiler -> included Directories 
[with key symbol] /home/ec2-user/gst/master/gstreamer
```

The password for the PPK is not saved in NetBeans.

```
myScript.c 
#include <gst/gst.h>
```

On remote host host I have the file

```
/home/ec2-user/gst/master/gstreamer/gst/gst.c 
/home/ec2-user/gst/master/gstreamer/gst/gst.h
```

Thanks 
Art